# Connect to dynamic database for one model in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-7

I want to connect second database in Laravel for one model. The second database configuration pass from the controller. Please help me to develop this part.

**This is my controller**

`$userdata=App\User::get_userdata($dbname,$dbuser,$dbpassword)`

**This is my model**

```
public function get_userdata($dbname,$dbuser,$dbpassword){
$query=DB::connection(???)->table('users')->first(); 
return $query; 
}
```

Can I try with this? Or have any other way to do this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it

```
        config::set(['database.connections.userdb'=>[
          'driver' => 'mysql',
          'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
          'host' => env('DB_HOST','127.0.0.1'),
          'port' => env('DB_PORT','3306'),
          'database' => 'ABC',
          'username' => 'ABC',
          'password' => 'ABC'
        ]]);

DB::connection('userdb')->table('usermas')
```